# Find list in list of list if element there

Tags: python

Advice please the most efficient and compact method to do this elementary task:

I want to create an output list with lists if element from input list in lists, otherwise just element in unit list:

```py
input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
lists = [[1,3,5],[7,9,11]]

# my solution:
output = []
for i in input_list:
    appended = False
    for sublist in lists:
        if i in sublist:
            output.append(list(sublist))
            appended = True
            break
    if not appended:
        output.append([i])

output
[[1, 3, 5],
 [2],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [4],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [6],
 [7, 9, 11],
 [8],
 [7, 9, 11],
 [10],
 [7, 9, 11]]
```

please don't base your solution by even numbers, it's just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to simplify your code:

```py
output = []
for i in input_list:
    for sublist in lists:
        if i in sublist:
            output.append(list(sublist))
            break
    else:
        output.append([i])
```

The `else` block at the end of a `for` loop will be executed whenever the loop wasn't terminated by a `break` statement (see the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)). So that eliminates the need for your `appended` flag.

I'm not going to go for "most efficient", but for "compact", you can use a list comprehension, and use the `next` function to do the search, providing a second argument to use as the fallback value in case the search doesn't find anything.

```
output = [
    next((list(sublist) for sublist in lists if i in sublist), [i])
    for i in input_list
]
```

Comment: exactly what is needed!